# UIDocumentInteractionController doesn't work with Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

I need to share an image file to Instagram, and according to Instagram doc: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/, I can use Document Interaction to implement this, but it just doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
        let img = UIImage(named: "test.jpg")
        let kInstagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://")
        let kUTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram" // testing "com.instagram.photo" too
        let instagramCaption = "TESTING"
        let kfileNameExtension = "instagram.igo" // testing "jpg"/"ig" too

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(kInstagramURL!) {
            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            if urls.count == 0 {
                print("Not found")
                return
            }
            let url = urls[0].appendingPathComponent(kfileNameExtension)
            print("URL", url)
            // OUPUT: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F14B18CB-5CD4-47AD-8257-E2288C23181E/Documents/instagram.igo
            do {
                try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 1.0)?.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
                print("WRITEN", url) // Written successfully, no error
            } catch {
                //TODO: issue error on UI
                print("WRITE ERROR: \(error)")
            }

            let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
            var rect = CGRect.zero
            let view = self.view

            documentInteractionController.delegate = DocInteractionResponder() // tried nil, same result
            documentInteractionController.uti = kUTI


            // adding caption for the image
            documentInteractionController.annotation = ["InstagramCaption": instagramCaption]
            documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: rect, in: view!, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            //TODO: warn from dialog
        }
```

I have tried many things within this code snippet (see comments), but the result is the same: after I tap instagram in the menu, nothing happens.

I thought it may be caused by other code in my app, so I create a blank app (with one simple UIViewController) and put this code in. It doesn't work.

I have read almost all answers on SO related to `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Does this happen to you? Is this the problem with iOS 11 (just upgraded my phone), or maybe Instagram stop supporting Document Interaction?

Comment: Not related to your question but worths mentioning. From the docs **To check whether a collection is empty, use its isEmpty property instead of comparing count to zero. Unless the collection guarantees random-access performance, calculating count can be an O(n) operation.
Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to RandomAccessCollection; otherwise, O(n), where n is the length of the collection.**

Comment: Here is an example on how to share any file type to any app (including Instagram of iOS 11.0.2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457518/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the tip. But the code in your answer doesn't work for me. Strange...

Comment: The code doesn’t work is vague. I have never tested to use it to share to a single App but it does show Instagram for me here in my App

Comment: Yes, Instagram shows in the menu. But tapping it doesn't trigger an app switch, I have tested Whatsapp, too.

Comment: I've tested here sharing to Instagram does work but it actually doesn't open the App.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @CoderACJHP Nope

Answer (score 5):

I just came across the same issue today, and I was able to solve it by declaring the `UIDocumentInteractionController` as a class-level property in the view controller, to prevent it from getting deallocated too soon.

Comment: This fixed it for me too, thanks was pulling my hair out!