# How can I write a file in a folder located at Apple's Files App in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I followed the Swift project UsingFiles [github](https://github.com/timrichardsn/Supporting-Files-in-iOS-11/blob/master/UsingFiles/ViewController.swift) and its [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1UNnsodJxc) to write files in my SwiftUI project. The project UsingFiles can write files to Files APP and then the writing files can be seen in the Files APP. But I followed the code as following, the files cannot be seen in Files APP.

```
let file = "\(UUID().uuidString).txt"
let contents = "Some text..."

let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

do {
    try contents.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
}
catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

The UsingFiles writing files is `file:///Users/fmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/11111111-881E-488A-9571-E61B83EB6062/data/Containers/Data/Application/11111111-AF89-4B15-B3B5-E13A63A19F8D/Documents/E018F056-83EA-4D70-87C4-16F755AA404A.txt`.

My writing files is `file:///Users/fmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/11111111-881E-488A-9571-E61B83EB6062/data/Containers/Data/Application/11111111-B191-4ACD-98B1-004E619C2EC7/Documents/C9E0F52E-040F-4647-94A3-88E0DA171AB5.txt`

I can find the writing files of UsingFiles in the directory `UsingFiles` as following:
[image]

But I cannot find the writing file in Files APP in my SwiftUI project. Is there something wrong of the code in SwiftUI? Why I cannot find the writing file in Files APP？

Comment: What do you mean by  “ I cannot find the writing file in Files APP”? Your file is showing inside onMyPhone location

Comment: @Leo, I mean the file is not in onMyPhone. I cannot find the file on my phone.

Comment: You have posted a screenshot of your file. It is inside your documents directory.

Comment: The UsingFile can export file to documents directory. But I cannot export file to document directory in my APP by the code I pasted.

Comment: Your file it is not inside Files app. It is already inside your Documents. You have to learn how to browse/list your files

Comment: @Leo Thanks. I understand your meaning. I will search it.

Comment: @Leo The same as you say that the file has been written in the Documents and I can read it by `try String(contentsOf: fileURL)`. Could you tell me how to show them in Files APP? Why the UsingFiles can show them in Files APP?

Comment: Creating your own file browser it is not a trivial task. If you want the same look/options of the Files App you can use UIDocumentBrowserViewController. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app

Comment: Thanks. But I want to write the txt file out of my APP's sandbox and share it to other people or send the written file by email. So the written file should be shown in Files--On My Phone. Then how to write the file to Files APP directly like the project UsingFiles?

Comment: There is no way to programmatically save a file out of your APP Bundle. You need to ask the user to choose the location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456481/how-to-write-a-file-to-a-folder-located-at-apples-files-app-in-swift/46457518#46457518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already posted in comments you can NOT programmatically save a file out of your APP Bundle. You can use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` and ask the user to choose the location where the file is supposed to be written.

So if you are working with SwiftUI this gets a bit more complicated than the regular Storyboard approach as you can see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457518/2303865) because you need to implement `UIViewControllerRepresentable` for `UIDocumentInteractionController`:

---

```
struct DocumentInteractionController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    fileprivate var isExportingDocument: Binding<Bool>
    fileprivate let viewController = UIViewController()
    fileprivate let documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController

    init(_ isExportingDocument: Binding<Bool>, url: URL) {
        self.isExportingDocument = isExportingDocument
        documentInteractionController = .init(url: url)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentInteractionController>) -> UIViewController { viewController }

    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentInteractionController>) {
        if isExportingDocument.wrappedValue && documentInteractionController.delegate == nil {
            documentInteractionController.uti = documentInteractionController.url?.typeIdentifier ?? "public.data, public.content"
            documentInteractionController.name = documentInteractionController.url?.localizedName
            documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: controller.view.frame, in: controller.view, animated: true)
            documentInteractionController.delegate = context.coordinator
            documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordintor { .init(self) }
}
```

---

And its Coordinator:

```
class Coordintor: NSObject, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    let documentInteractionController: DocumentInteractionController
    init(_ controller: DocumentInteractionController) {
        documentInteractionController = controller
    }
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController { documentInteractionController.viewController }

    func documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
        controller.delegate = nil
        documentInteractionController.isExportingDocument.wrappedValue = false
    }
}
```

---

Now you can create your DocumentInteraction View and its previews:

```
struct DocumentInteraction: View {
    @State private var isExportingDocument = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Export Document") { self.isExportingDocument = true }
            .background(DocumentInteractionController($isExportingDocument,
                url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "pdf")!))
        }
    }
}

struct DocumentInteraction_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View { DocumentInteraction() }
}
```

---

You will need those helpers as well:

```
extension URL {
    var typeIdentifier: String? { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier }
    var localizedName: String? { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey]))?.localizedName }
}
```

---

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3or66mqwi2urjky/Document%20Interaction%20Controller%20UI.zip?dl=1)

Answer (score 5):

I used UIActivityViewController to save a file on my phone.
It's simple and works.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: wirtieFile) {
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
    }

    func wirtieFile() -> Void{
        let file = "test.txt"
        let dir = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(file)
        let contents = "test..."
        do {
           try contents.write(to: dir!, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch {
           print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var filesToShare = [Any]()
        filesToShare.append(dir!)
        let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: filesToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good but its not saving other file, like doc, pdf etc.
If you can make your solution dynamic for all files it will be very good.

Answer (score 3):

Try add “Application supports iTunes file sharing” and “Supports opening documents in place” to “info.plist”. And change them value to true.

Comment: You should add some code to your solution in order to help OP

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To me this answer is perfectly clear. I did exactly what it says to do, and it fixed the problem. This should be the accepted answer. Since one comment here requested a code example and another said the answer is "unclear" (I disagree) I posted my own answer -- but all credit to lilunxp!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is entirely based on the earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75437589/668253) by  [lilunxp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14804038/lilunxp). If you like my answer please also like that answer.

I think the accepted answer is an overkill for what the OP wants. My understanding is that the OP simply wants to be able to write a file from the app, and have that file be visible and accessible from within Apple's **Files** app. That is very easy to do.

The all important thing is to do exactly what the answer from [lilunxp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14804038/lilunxp) says to do: "Try add 'Application supports iTunes file sharing' and 'Supports opening documents in place' to 'info.plist'. And change them value to true". That seems crystal clear, but just in case, here's a screenshot from Xcode 15.2 that shows how: just add the bottom two lines.

[image]

The OP already has the right code, but let me repeat it here and embellish a little by also creating subdirectories that the user can browse from Apple's **Files** app. This is the entire code needed:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Make files user can access outside this app") {
                makeFilesThatUserCanAccessOutsideThisApp()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

func makeFilesThatUserCanAccessOutsideThisApp() {
    guard let docFolder = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        fatalError()
    }
    let contents = "Some text..."
    let mySOFileNameA = "MySOFileA.txt"
    let mySOFileNameB = "MySOFileB.txt"
    let mySOFolderUrl = docFolder.appendingPathComponent("MySOFolder")

    do {
        // write one file at the top level:
        try contents.write(to: docFolder.appendingPathComponent(mySOFileNameA), atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        // write two files into the subdirectory (after first creating the subdirectory if necessary):
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: mySOFolderUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        try contents.write(to: mySOFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(mySOFileNameA), atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        try contents.write(to: mySOFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(mySOFileNameB), atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Now the rest is just a matter of opening Apple's **Files** app, then selecting **Browse** > **On My iPhone**. This is what it looks like in iOS 17.3:

[image: Views from Apple's Files app]

Both views are from Apple's **Files** app. The left view shows a "folder" for my app (I called it **My SO App**). The system automatically creates this "top level folder": notice in the code above that it was only necessary to use `FileManager.default.createDirectory` to create the subdirectory. The right view shows the contents of the top level folder. As expected it shows a file and a subdirectory (that contains two items). The user is able to open these text files, and easily "share it to other people or send the written file by email" as the OP expressed in a comment.