# iOS Document Picker crashes when picking a PDF on a real device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I try to create a Document Picker for my iOS app.

Here is my code (I wrapped the UIDocumentPickerViewController in my SwiftUI View, with UIViewControllerRepresentable):

```
import SwiftUI
import MobileCoreServices

struct DocumentPickerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var callback: (Data) -> ()

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(documentController: self)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(
        _ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController,
        context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPickerViewController>) {
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .open)
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        var documentController: DocumentPickerViewController

        init(documentController: DocumentPickerViewController) {
            self.documentController = documentController
        }

        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            guard let url = urls.first else { return }

            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path))
            let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: url.path)
            let file = UploadFileData(fileName: "\(url)", fileType: .file, fileData: data!)
            let dataFile = file.fileData as Data
            
            documentController.callback(dataFile)
        }
    }
}

enum UploadFileType{
    case photo
    case file
}

struct UploadFileData {
    var fileName: String
    var fileType: UploadFileType
    var fileData: NSData
}

var file: UploadFileData?
```

It works on my Simulator, but when I pick a PDF on a real device, I get the following error:
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file MyApp/DocumentPickerViewController.swift, line 44

ie for line: `let dataFile = file.fileData as Data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue there is that you are using the wrong mode when defining the type of file transfer operation used by the document picker.  `.open` is used to open an external file located outside your app’s sandbox. What you need is to use `.import` it will create a temporary file that will allow you to load its contents or move/copy the file to a permanent location. If it doesn't solve you issue check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62329771/2303865) on how to implement your DocumentPickerViewController coordinator

```
let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIDocumentPickerViewController via UIViewControllerRepresentable then use initializer with asCopy parameter

```
let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.pdf], asCopy: true)
```

if ios target above ios 14 then use .fileImporter presentation modifier

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showDocumentPicker,
                      allowedContentTypes: [.pdf],
                      allowsMultipleSelection: true)
        { result in
            // processing results Result<[URL], Error>
        }
```