# Displaying folder names from UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to allow the user to select a folder in which to save a text file. All is working except for being able to display a message confirming the location of the saved file.

The screenshot shows a typical list of folders displayed by `UIDocumentPickerViewController` that the user can select:

[image: UIDocumentPickerViewController]

The folder names displayed to the user are those expected. However, the URLs returned by `UIDocumentPickerViewController` differ from those displayed and are not suitable for use in a confirmation message:

```
.../data/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs
.../data/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop
.../data/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents
.../data/Library/Mobile Documents/3L68KQB4HG~com~readdle~CommonDocuments/Documents
.../data/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads
.../data/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~net~jermware~gjLists/Documents
.../data/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~is~workflow~my~workflows/Documents
.../data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/EB502BF4-9272-466F-9F5D-0CA97E35E687/File Provider Storage
```

In some of the URLs I could use just the last path component e.g. **Desktop**, **Documents**, **Downloads**, but for some it's the second from last path component e.g. **gjLists**, and for others the path is completely different e.g. **Documents by Readdle**, **Shortcuts** and **On My iPhone**.

This makes it very difficult/impossible to reliably parse the URL to extract the folder displayed to the user by `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

After some investigation, I found the `FileManager.default.displayName` API which returns the display name of the file or directory at a specified path.

This improves things somewhat, giving the following folder names for the above URLs:

```
iCloud Drive
iCloud Drive
iCloud Drive
Documents by Readdle
Downloads
gjLists
Shortcuts
File Provider Storage
```

I now have the correct names for **Documents by Readdle**, **Downloads**, **gjLists** and **Shortcuts**, but just **iCloud Drive** for **Desktop** and **Documents** and still **'File Provider Storage'** for **'On My Phone'**.

Does anyone know how, given the URLs returned by `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, I can get the folder name as displayed in the picker? Displaying a confirmation message to the user saying the file was successfully saved to the **'File Provider Storage'** folder rather than **'On My iPhone'** is going to cause no end of confusion.

Comment: So you are using a method which it’s intent is to import files to allow the user to pick a folder to save a file?  If so you are using the wrong method. What you are looking for is UIDocumentInteractionController https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456481/how-to-write-a-file-to-a-folder-located-at-apples-files-app-in-swift/46457518#46457518

Comment: IMO you should always save your file locally and allow the user to export the file if he wants to. I don’t think a confirmation is necessary.

Comment: @LeoDabus (Offtopic for single files, anyway) Well, there is a valid use case for misusing the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to select a folder: if the user is going to store multiple files at the same time. The alternative, `UIActivityViewController`, is not able to set filenames for Data() objects, so "picking" a folder fills the gap.

Comment: @FrederikWinkelsdorf yes you can select a folder but note that AFAIK every time you launch an App the url will path change (sandboxing). So I wouldn't count on it for later usage.

Comment: @LeoDabus Absolutely right, this is better used as a one-time selection. Good catch!

Comment: @LeoDabus It's possible to re-use an URL returned by a file picker: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417795-bookmarkdata

Comment: @AdrianLabbé yes but that's a security-scoped bookmark. You can't simply save an URL.

Comment: @gjerman Did you ever find an answer to this question?  I am facing this exact problem.

Comment: @KeithTheBiped I moved my backup/restore functionality into a SwiftUI view and use the .fileExporter and .fileImporter methods to do what I need. Works well for my needs.