# How can I display my App documents in the Files app for iPhone

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to show my data in my app in the Files app on my iPhone
I searched a lot and did everything right, I don't know where the error is

```
func fileManger(nameFolder: String) {

    let manager = FileManager.default
    let DecomentFolder = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last
    let Folder = DecomentFolder?.appendingPathComponent("\(nameFolder)")

    do {
        try manager.createDirectory(at: Folder!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: [:])
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Also here I am sending the value to be a folder

```
@objc func alertNewFolder () {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create an album", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
    alert.textFields![0].placeholder = "name album"
    alert.textFields![0].textAlignment = .right
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "save", style: .default, handler: { ـ in
        if let textFileds = alert.textFields {
            let links = textFileds[0].text
            self.arrS1.append(addCatogrey(nameCatog: links!, imageSection: UIImage(named: "folder")))
// Here Send FileManager
            helperCoding().fileManger(nameFolder: links!)
            self.collection.reloadData()
        }
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In the Simulators it saved in the Documents folder here correctly

```
/Users/badrshammry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7986A27F-7026-45E1-9073-78CCD6A9B90A/data/Containers/Data/Application/3173C4DC-BCDE-41B9-89E1-6E8D9B52EF25/Documents
```

Comment: What makes you think that saving it in your library folder would show on Files App?

Comment: I don't know, I guessed this from research

Comment: What is actually your question?

Comment: I just want to show files in the Files app

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you would like to expose your App document files inside Apple's Files App you need to include the `"Supports Document Browser"` key in your info plist file and set it to YES:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to specify certain files that should not be displayed, or should i write those files somewhere else?

Comment: if you don't want to expose certain files to the user you should write them to the app support directory. take a look at [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) docs

Comment: **Use this directory to store all app data files except those associated with the user’s documents. For example, you might use this directory to store app-created data files, configuration files, templates, or other fixed or modifiable resources that are managed by the app. An app might use this directory to store a modifiable copy of resources contained initially in the app’s bundle. A game might use this directory to store new levels purchased by the user and downloaded from a server.**

Comment: **All content in this directory should be placed in a custom subdirectory whose name is that of your app’s bundle identifier or your company.
In iOS, the contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes and iCloud.**

Comment: Very much appreciated.

Comment: Any other way to do it? There’s no plist on Swift Playgrounds projects and I need to stay in one for multitouch development.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I needed to search so long for this simple answer!

Answer (score 9):

Add these two keys to 'info.plist' -

```
...
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
...
```

After this, files saved in '.documentDirectory' will appear in 'Files App' inside a folder with your app name.

If editing 'info.plist' in Xcode then add below keys -

```
Application supports iTunes file sharing = YES
Supports opening documents in place = YES
```

[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufagY.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am running iOS 17.0.1 and Xcode 15.2 and simple going into your project target, clicking on the info tab. and adding "Supports Documents Browser == YES" under Custom iOS Target Properties works perfectly fine!

If I go into the files App and click on "On My iPhone" there is now a folder for my app.

Please note, you may actually need to actually add a file for the folder to appear. For testing purposes, the following will do:

```
func saveToLocalDirectory() {
    let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let URL = StorageArchive.local.appendingPathComponent("testfile").appendingPathExtension("txt")
    let testString: String = "Test string to write in text file."
    do {
        try testString.write(to: URL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        print("Saving was a BIG success.")
    } catch {
        print("Saving Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set `Supports Document Browser` has to be set in `Custom iOS Target Properties`in the `info` tab

`info.plist` is no more from Xcode 13

Anyhow, it does not work.  The files App will not find files in the your app's bundle.  They need to be "shared" (In `SwiftUI` use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`)

But your App will not have a directory in the file structure visible to the Files App.  Adding that folder is still a mystery

See: [How can folders visible to FIles app be created by App programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70776775/16675319)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is actually the correct answer!  Set Supports Document Browser = YES in "Custom iOS Target Properties" for the target does work.  Doing it in the info.plist directly does not work, was not working for me at all.  As @Wrog points out, it must have changed after Xcode 13.

Comment: @KeithTheBiped If your documents folder is empty it will not appear there. Note that the bundle folder can not be shared.