# Swift: Saving an image into a custom folder in the Files app

Tags: ios, swift, filesystems

I would like to save images from my app to the Files app

[image]

in the following hierarchy:

```
Files
  MyAppFolder
    FolderA
      fileA1.png
      fileA2.png
      fileA3.png
    FolderB
      fileB1.png
      fileB2.png
      fileB3.png
```

I am trying to use the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344822/saving-image-and-then-loading-it-in-swift-ios):

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
    guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
        return false
    }
    guard let directory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) as NSURL else {
        return false
    }
    do {
        try data.write(to: directory.appendingPathComponent("fileName.png")!)
        return true
    } catch {   
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
}
```

But the file is no where to be found in the Files app.

I  guess the url to the Files should be something else. But what?

Comment: You can't save files out of your app bundle. Only the user can do it

Comment: Not related to your question but your code is outdated `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` has been renamed to `image.pngData()`

Comment: I would also remove the guard from the let directory, change `try?` to `try` and move it inside your do try catch logic. This will allow you to do not force unwrap its value when writing it to disk. Btw don't cast to `NSURL`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456481/how-to-write-a-file-to-a-folder-located-at-apples-files-app-in-swift

Comment: If you would like to expose your app bundle files inside Files OnMyPhone you can check this post [How can I display my App documents in the Files app for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70613710/2303865)