# Open iOS Application files from Finder

Tags: ios, swift

I have found out, that some applications are able to store their files in that way, so one can connect their device to a Mac and access them via Finder > Locations > *Device Name* > Files. Are these capabilities included in public iOS API? If so, how can I make some of my app generated files to be publicly accessed?

[image]

Comment: may be this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613514/how-can-i-display-my-app-documents-in-the-files-app-for-iphone

Comment: Take a look at [UIFileSharingEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uifilesharingenabled) and [UISupportsDocumentBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uisupportsdocumentbrowser)

Comment: Thanks @RickyMo your answer is correct  UIFileSharingEnabled did all job to show documents folder inside Finder for me!