# Swift on iOS writes to file in Documents directory but file cannot be found on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write a simple text file into the Documents folder on my iPhone from within my Swift app. The code runs successfully, i.e., I get the "All Good!" message, but I cannot locate the file anywhere in the Files app.

I am using Xcode 15.2 on a MacBook running macOS 14.2.1. My device target is an iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 17.2.1.

Here's my code:

```
let docDir = URL.documentsDirectory
let fileURL = docDir.appendingPathComponent("testfile.txt", conformingTo: .text)
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let sampleString = "test test test"
do {
    let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: fileURL)
    fileHandle.write(Data(sampleString.utf8))
    try fileHandle.close()
    print("All Good!")
} catch {
    print("File error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: You are not writing to “the” Documents folder on your iPhone. There is no such folder. You are writing to the Documents folder inside your app’s sandbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70613710/2303865)