# Tableview cells data is changing when I scroll vertically in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4

I have developed an iOS app it has couple of tableviews. It works fine if I did not scroll, if i scroll tableview data inside cells data is changing pls make me perfect here.
Here is the code below for first table which will have UISwitch and text.[image] For reference pls watch video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hVHnAyGnQFrhvzLSoJjeMzG6wlfxoURm

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if let d = self.data {
       return d.count
   }
   return  0

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if let _ = cell {} else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    if let d = self.data {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = d[indexPath.row]
        let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
        switchView.setOn(self.isFolderIsAdded(folderName: d[indexPath.row]), animated: true)
        switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        cell?.accessoryView = switchView

    }
    return cell!
}

func isFolderIsAdded(folderName:String) -> Bool{
    for   val in listOfSelectedFolder{
        if(folderName == val ){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){
    if let d = self.data {
        if(sender.isOn){
            self.delegate?.selectedSubFolder(name: d[sender.tag])
           } else {
            self.delegate?.deleteFilesFromFolder(folderName: d[sender.tag])
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second table code which will have image view and text. I created custom cell named TableViewCell [image]. For reference pls watch video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11snH5_henOadVCVqS9bL5SZRjcZF3vEU

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewContent.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    if let _ = contentModel[self.currentMode]{
        tempArr1 = appendFolderName(files: contentModel[self.currentMode]!, name: self.currentMode)!

    }
    if indexPath.row < tempArr1.count {
        cell.setupCellData(text: tempArr1[indexPath.row])
    }else{
        if let res = self.getFilesFromSubFolder(contentName: self.currentMode, folderName: self.SelectedFolder) {
            cell.setupCellData(text: res[indexPath.row - tempArr1.count] )

        }
    }
    let bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
    return cell
}

func setupCellData(text:String) {
    let temarr = text.components(separatedBy: "@")
    let str =  temarr.last?.capitalized
    let strq = temarr.first?.lowercased()
    let newstr = strq?.components(separatedBy: "-")
    let val = newstr?.last
    let content = val!.lowercased() + "@" +  str!
    self.ContentLabel.text = content
    if ((self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("pps"))!||(self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("pptx"))!||(self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("ppt"))!){
        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "table_Content_ppt")
    }else if ((self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("mp4"))! || (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("mp3"))!){
        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "table_Content")
    }else if (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("pdf"))!{
        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pdf_content")
    }else if (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("url"))!{
        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "url_content")
    }else if (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("exe"))!{
        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "application_content")
    }else if (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("doc"))!{
        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "word_content")
    }else if (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("bat"))!{
        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cmd")
    }
    else if (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("lnk"))!{
        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cmd")
    }
    else if ((self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("png"))! || (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("jpg"))! || (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("jpeg"))! || (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("psd"))! || (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("tiff"))! || (self.ContentLabel.text?.contains("gif"))!) {

        imageData.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img")

    }else{
        imageData.image = nil

    }

}
```

I have added prepareForReuse()method  in tableview cell class but still result is same content is changed after scroll.

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    // Clear all content based views and their actions here
     imageData.image = nil
    ContentLabel.text = ""
}
```

Comment: You need to clear the reused cell content before adding new data on it.

Comment: Btw you should update your Xcode to the current version.

Comment: @LeoDabus Pls help me on that I'm new to iOS. Thanks

Comment: Just clear it. If it is an image set it to nil, and so on after you dequeue your cell

Comment: I have to clear in cellForRowAt indexPath?? pls give some more idea in which case I need to clear . For example UISwitch+Text first table scroll pls post your answer. Thanks

Comment: Yes once you get a reused cell there just clear it below dequeueReusableCell

Comment: Not related to your question but you should use the fileURL Type identifier resourceValue to check your file type. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34772517/2303865

Comment: Check the link above on how to get your file localized name as well

Comment: I added at the end of my question please check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203524/discussion-between-rahul-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: erase your cell content unconditionally

Comment: Unrelated but why is the data source array declared as optional? You can get rid of a lot of unnecessary `if let` expressions if you declare the array as non-optional.

Comment: Okay I will remove if let statements but as others said not able to implement resetting cell data after scroll pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the `listOfSelectedFolder` array in `switchChanged`.

Assuming `self.data` will be declared as non-optional change the method to

```
@objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch){
    let folderName = self.data[sender.tag]
    if sender.isOn {
        listOfSelectedFolder.append(folderName)
        self.delegate?.selectedSubFolder(name: folderName)
    } else {
       if let index = listOfSelectedFolder.index(of: folderName) {
          listOfSelectedFolder.remove(at: index)
       }
       self.delegate?.deleteFilesFromFolder(folderName: folderName)
    }
}
```

The other methods can be optimized

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let folderName = self.data[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = folderName
    let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
    switchView.setOn(self.isFolderAdded(folderName: folderName), animated: true)
    switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.accessoryView = switchView
    return cell
}

func isFolderAdded(folderName: String) -> Bool{
    return listOfSelectedFolder.contains(folderName)
}
```

However it's highly recommended to use a custom struct as data model and add a `isSelected` property. And declare `listOfSelectedFolder` as a Set.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your cell class

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // Clear all content based views and their actions here
    }
```

Comment: I added prepareforreuse in cell class.  I have one image view and label how do I reset it:  imageData = nil
        ContentLabel = nil. IS this correct?

Comment: no, you should do this: imageData.image = nil & contentLabel.text = ""

Comment: **For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) should always reset all content when reusing a cell** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse

Comment: It's wrong, anything may be different in cells most reset. something like layout or color or... that is same in all cells doesn't need to reset. read this: https://fluffy.es/solve-duplicated-cells/

Comment: I added  prepareForReuse() in cell class but still content is changing after scroll pls check I added code at the end of my question.

Comment: it's not logical you wrote? why did you do it?                                                               if indexPath.row < tempArr1.count {
        cell.setupCellData(text: tempArr1[indexPath.row])
    }else{
        if let res = self.getFilesFromSubFolder(contentName: self.currentMode, folderName: self.SelectedFolder) {
            cell.setupCellData(text: res[indexPath.row - tempArr1.count] )

        }
    }

Comment: The problem is not to clear the content, the problem is that the data model is not updated properly in `switchChanged`. Implementing `prepareForReuse ` is pointless in this case.

Comment: @vadian Rahul said: It works fine if I did not scroll, if i scroll tableview data inside cells data is changing. Means scrolled cell views do not update avoid its data.

Comment: Yes because `cellForRowAt` is called again and `isFolderIsAdded` returns the wrong value if it's not being updated in the switch action.

Comment: Of course the array most update on changes, you right. anyway table views with dynamic contents needs to prepareForReuse

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue before and I tried to add layoutIfNeeded() inside the cellForRowAt and it solved the problem.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if let _ = cell {} else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    if let d = self.data {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = d[indexPath.row]
        let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
        switchView.setOn(self.isFolderIsAdded(folderName: d[indexPath.row]), animated: true)
        switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        cell?.accessoryView = switchView
cell?.layoutIfNeeded() <--- Add this

    }
    return cell!
}
```